# Merge values to table from Java

Tags: java, sql, csv, jdbc, db2

I have a java program that reads a csv file line by line and does MERGE in the table using the Merge statement provided by DB2.

For example, If i have a 1000 lines in CSV it would run the executeUpdate 1000 times.

My challenge is that i run this script every hour so there is a possibility that new entries would come into the csv file or values would get updated or rows might be deleted (sometimes the row will come again in future)

I think i am doing the insert if not exist and update if exist part correct but i am not sure how do i do the delete part for rows that were inserted in the past but no longer in the latest csv file ?

Also what would be an ideal situation here to avoid doing 1000 insert statement do i use prepared statement ? Can someone give me an example ?

```
String sql_merge = " MERGE INTO IM4BMX.IEMCOMPUTER_DETAILS AS A USING (VALUES ('"+ComputerID+"', '"+Environment+"')) AS A_TMP ( ComputerID , Environment) ON A.ComputerID = A_TMP.ComputerID   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ComputerID = '"+ComputerID+"', Environment = '"+Environment+"' WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( ComputerID , Environment ) VALUES (A_TMP.ComputerID, A_TMP.Environment )  ELSE IGNORE ";            

stmt.executeUpdate(sql_merge);
```

Comment: If your CSV file is the canonical source for the data in this table, why would you not simply truncate / load the contents of the table with the data in the CSV file?

Comment: @IanBjorhovde how do i import csv file to db2 table using my Java program ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a when not matched clause to your query.

Ex.  WHEN NOT MATCHED 
              THEN DELETE

If you CSV file contains data that does not match what is in the DB then it should delete that row.

Look at this link for further information.

[Merge Statement Explained](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/merge?lang=en)